# Adding checkbox in header of programmatically created div

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I have a **programmatically** created `dojox.grid.DataGrid` whose structure is

```
var nodeSelectGridStructure = [
    {
        "field": "select",
        "width": "10%",
        "name": "Select"
    },
    {
        "field": "fldJobName",
        "width": "30%",
        "name": "Collection Job Name"
    },
    {
        "field": "fldNodes",
        "width": "60%",
        "name": "Nodes"
    }
];
```

I want to add a checkbox in the header of the column "select". Is there a way to obtain the dom-node of the header of "select" column so that I can add the checkbox there?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I did a lot of hit-and-trials and found this -

1) we first have to set the `escapeHTMLInData: false` in grid definition

2) Then in the structure we have to add the tag in the header name itself as following

```
var nodeSelectGridStructure = [
    {
        "field": "select",
        "width": "10%",
        "name": "<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"\"/>"
    },
    {
        "field": "fldJobName",
        "width": "30%",
        "name": "Collection Job Name"
    },
    {
    "field": "fldNodes",
        "width": "60%",
        "name": "Nodes"
    }
];
```

This worked for me. thanks for the reply! I'll try that also.

Answer (score 0):

The template has an attach point called viewsHeaderNode which can be used for accessing the DOM node.

```
dijit.byId("data_grid_id").viewsHeaderNode
```

I haven't tried adding content to it manually myself but good luck :)